# error during installation of opencv on ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I am following http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

for the installation of Opencv on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

In the step 2 given by **Step #2: Download the OpenCV source**, I do not face any issues with the command

```
$ wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip
```

However when I try to execute the command

```
$ unzip opencv.zip
```

I get the following error

```
Archive:  opencv.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of opencv.zip or
        opencv.zip.zip, and cannot find opencv.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Results of

```
du -hsc opencv.zip
```

are as follows

```
0   opencv.zip
0   total
```

Result of

```
ls -l
```

on my Home directory is as follows

```
3.1.0.zip
3.1.0.zip.1
3.1.0.zip.2
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
op
opencv-3.1.0
opencv_contrib.zip
opencv.zip
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
wget-log
```

Is there something wrong with the link as the folder is getting downloaded but is not having any content as obtained from du command. Any alternative(s)?

Comment: Yes there is someting wrong with the link (`404 not found`). You can download direct from the opencv website http://opencv.org/releases.html

Comment: @steeldriver, Thank you.I have downloaded the folder...what next?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip -O opencv-3.2.0.zip

unzip opencv-3.2.0.zip